# Correct way to declare a defaultdict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am currently trying to use a `defaultdict` in a unittest.
I declare it this way.

```
dic_response = defaultdict(list)
dic_response['d']['DisplayStatusList'] = [{
    'DisplayStatusID': 26,
    'Name': 'To sell'
}]
```

It fails with

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/maazza/PycharmProjects/django_test/app_tester/tests.py", line
>   422, in test_save_display_status
>       'Name': 'To sell', TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: I know this is old, but a [mcve] would have been greatly beneficial in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're using this, you should be declaring `defaultdict(dict)`. What's happening right now is you're accessing `dic_response['d']`, which creates a new list (which should be a dict, but you asked for `defaultdict(list)` so you're getting a list). Then that new list is being used as `new_list['DisplayStatusList']`, which is producing the exception you're seeing.

Comment: by the way if you could tell me why it failed on the 'To sell' and not on the 'DisplayStatuslist' it will be perfect

Comment: @maazza: Haven't a clue why it's picking that line number, sorry. It *should* be complaining about the `dic_response['d']['DisplayStatusList']` line. There might be something in the rest of your code that would explain it, but I'd have to see it to be sure. (And that is NOT a request to post the whole of your code: posting 400+ lines of code to stackoverflow.com is generally frowned upon. The way to use this site is precisely what you did: isolate the smallest snippet that causes the problem then post that snippet.)

Answer (score 4):

You created a dictionary where each key has a list as its value, but then you tried to access one of those list items using string index...

Looks like you wanted to create a default dictionary of dictionaries...

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic_response = defaultdict(dict)
>>> dic_response['d']['DisplayStatusList'] = [{'DisplayStatusID': 26, 'Name': 'To sell'}]
>>> dic_response
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'d': {'DisplayStatusList': [{'DisplayStatusID': 26, 'Name': 'To sell'}]}})
```